# How to change the priority of chrome extensions both overriding new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

So my problem is we developed an extension which overrides default new tab page into over own page
this works fine when the only extension overriding the new tab is our but if the user installs
a similar extension then the new extension takes priority.

How can I make my extension overrides the new tab and don't make allow the newly installed extension
to override it.

Comment: There's no way. The most recently installed extension always wins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just reinstall the old extension so that the old one becomes the new one and the new one will become the old one and the previously old one (the one you wanted) will change the new tab.